# Convert List of bytes to memorystream without using ToArray()

Tags: c#

How can I save my `list<byte>` to `MemoryStream()` without using `ToArray()` or creating new array ?

This is my current method:

```
public Packet(List<byte> data)
{
    // Create new stream from data buffer
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data.ToArray()))
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            Length = reader.ReadInt16();
            pID = reader.ReadByte();
            Result = reader.ReadByte();
            Message = reader.ReadString();
            ID = reader.ReadInt32();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this so bad? The answers posted give you alternatives but I doubt they are any more efficient

Answer (score 2):

The `ToArray` solution is the most efficient solution possible using documented APIs. `MemoryStream` will not copy the array. It will just store it. So the only copy is in `List<T>.ToArray()`.

If you want to avoid that copy you need to pry `List<T>` open using reflection and access the backing array. I advise against that.

Instead, use a collection that allows you to obtain the backing array using legal means. Write your own, or use a `MemoryStream` in the first place.

A `List<T>` is not the most efficient way to move around bytes anyway. Storing them is fine, moving them usually has more overhead. For example, adding items bytewise will be far slower than a `memcpy`.

Comment: If possible, use a `byte[]` from the very beginning instead of `List<byte>`.

Comment: I was using byte[] , but i need dynamic arrays so list is more efficient than using array.resize multiple times.

Comment: @usr , thank you - this **MemoryStream will not copy the array. It will just store it.** answers to my question perfect.

Comment: @RoopeJärvenpää you can implement your own list that grows an array by a factor of two. That handles the growth and the idea to never copy the array contents.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
public Packet(List<byte> data)
{
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Loop list and write out bytes
        foreach(byte b in data)
            stream.WriteByte(b);

        // Reset stream position ready for read
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            Length = reader.ReadInt16();
            pID = reader.ReadByte();
            Result = reader.ReadByte();
            Message = reader.ReadString();
            ID = reader.ReadInt32();
        }
    }
}
```

But why do you have a list in the first place? Can't you pass it into the method as a `byte[]` to start with? It'd be interesting to see how you populate that list.

Comment: Well, i used Array.resize when i used byte[] to handle TCP packet streams. That caused my program to overwrite new array with previous arrays data - that could be fixed if i added thread sleep just after array creation.

AND what i read on internet, they say list is most efficient way to have dynamic array. And that is what i need.